# Bootstrap data-toggle and data-target not working

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

As I am new in Bootstrap and react. I am facing error when I click on add category button nothing is shown. I have applied data-toggle and data-target on add category button but its not working.

Here the code i'm using.
Showroom.js file.

```
import React from "react";

const ShowroomDashboard = () => {
/*********************** 
 * Views
************************/
 const showHeader = () => (
    <div className='bg-dark text-white py-4'>
        <div className = 'container'>

            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-md-6'>
                    <h1>
                        <i className= 'fas fa-home'> Showroom Dashboard</i>
                    </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

const showActionBtns = () => (
    <div className = 'bg-light my-2'>
        <div className ='container'>
            <div className ='row pb-3'>
                <div className ='col-md-4 my-1'>
                    <button className ='btn btn-outline-info btn-block' data-toggle= 'modal' data-target= '#addCategoryModal'>
                        <i className ='fas fa-plus'> Add Category </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className ='col-md-4 my-1'>
                    <button className ='btn btn-outline-warning btn-block'>
                        <i className ='fas fa-plus'> Add Car </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className ='col-md-4 my-1'>
                    <button className ='btn btn-outline-info btn-block'>
                        <i className ='fas fa-money-check-alt'> View Order </i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);

//id will be of same name as data target attribute in add category button
const showCategoryModal = () => (
    <div id='addCategoryModal' className= 'modal'>Inside modal</div>
);

/*********************** 
* Renderer
************************/

return (
    <section>
        {showHeader()}
        {showActionBtns()}
        {showCategoryModal()}
    </section>
);
};

export default ShowroomDashboard;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are using Bootstrap 4 ?
They are some changes from Bootstrap Version 4 to version 5!

For example data-toogle is now data-bs-toggle and data-target is now data-bs-target in Bootstrap 5

Comment: Thanks @Nick. This solves my problem but nothing is displaced when i click on add category button.

Comment: displayed* instead of displaced.

Comment: modal has the same changes. 

data-toggle= 'modal' should now be: 

data-bs-toggle= 'modal'.

Comment: when i click on add category nothing is displayed as in code i have const showCategoryModal = () => (
    <div id='addCategoryModal' className= 'modal'>Inside modal</div>
);

Comment: Change this: data-toggle= 'modal' data-target= '#addCategoryModal'   to: data-bs-toggle= 'modal' data-bs-target= '#addCategoryModal'

Comment: Thanks Nick. I have changed that earlier but my Div is ceating problem as it is not showing any thing which i sought out.